# tzwhere returns null at these coordinates , how can this be corrected?

Tags: python

```py
import datetime
import pytz
from tzwhere import tzwhere

tzwhere = tzwhere.tzwhere()

result = tzwhere.tzNameAt( 43.91517242, 39.32136118 ) #and this lat =47.44026597 lot = 141.97219224

print(result)
```

I'm trying to request a timezone, but I get a null response, help me fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I recommend you at least skim the documentation if you have problems with a library. It's right there on the [frontpage](https://github.com/pegler/pytzwhere): Apparently the data has holes and you are supposed to use a force parameter to get the nearest timezone instead.

Alternatively use an other library like [this one](https://github.com/jannikmi/timezonefinder).